# Can't get error message to show with WTForms _formhelpers to show on Flask webpage

Tags: forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, form-helpers

Apologies if this isn't worded very well. I can't seem to get any error messages to show when I haven't fulfilled the validation requirements. When I submit, the form is just refreshed without error messages such as "This field is required".

Also, when I do input data, `if form.validate_on_submit():` doesn't return the expected homepage, it once again just refreshes the page. I'm aware the form does nothing, I plan on adding the data submitted to a database but I'm stuck on this step. Can anybody help? Thanks.

app.py

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect
from flask_session import Session
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField #bool for checkbox
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length


# configure application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMENANT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Allows webpage to update html on refresh
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Itsasecret'
# configure CS50 library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///project.db")

# Usually separate routes, database and form stuff into different files and link together

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username =  StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)]) #80 is a special number (learn more)
    remember = BooleanField('Remember me')

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("homepage.html")

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect("/")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

login template

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

{% set active_page = 'login' %}

{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="ls-main">
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}        
        {{ render_field(form.username) }}
        {{ render_field(form.password, autocomplete="off") }}
        {{ render_field(form.remember) }}
        <div class="ls-div">
            <input class="ls-input, signinbutton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

_formhelpers.html

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return render_template("/")` is invalid.  I think you mean `return redirect("/")`

Of course you need `from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that mistake. I'm sure that once I figure out my problem that would have been the next thing I'd be getting confused about!

Comment: Did that fix the problem? If not, what is the new behavior? And, where is your ending `</dt>`?

Comment: I mustn't have refreshed it properly because nothing changed initially. But when I closed it and reopened it was fixed! Thank you so much, I was wracking my brains for ages assuming the problem was too big for me to fix alone. Can't believe it was so simple in the end. I've also fixed the ending `</dt>`. Thanks again!